# Ruby module inclusion with class methods and inheritance

Tags: ruby

I'm having a hard time understanding why the following doesn't work:

```
module M1
  def m1
    p 'm1'
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def m1c
      p 'm1c'
    end
  end

  def self.included base
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end
end

module M2
  include M1

  def m2
    p 'm2'
  end
end


class Foo
  include M2

  def hi
    p 'hi'
  end
end

Foo.new.hi => 'hi'
Foo.new.m1 => 'm1'
Foo.new.m2 => 'm2'
Foo.m1c => undefined method `m1c' for Foo:Class (NoMethodError)
```

All methods work as expected if I include `M1` directly in `Foo` but it seems DRYer to include it in `M2`. Am I misunderstanding modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `include M1` in `M2`, the instance methods of `M1` as well as the class methods coming from `ClassMethods` are incorporated into `M2` because of the `self.included` definition in `M1`.

But when you do `include M2` in `Foo`, you only include the instance methods of `M2`. The class methods of `M2` are not incorporated into `Foo`.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking the `included` hook would be called at each inclusion but it makes sense why it's only called when I include it in `M2`.

Comment: So just move `def self.included base; base.extend; ClassMethods; end` to `M2` and Bob's your uncle.